# Store sensitive variables in a repo - what's the 'right' approach

Tags: git, github

Bit of an open ended question. I have a project I would like to store on a public repo. To make the point suppose I have a single file, a docker-compose.yaml file of the form:

```
version: "3.5"
networks:
  collabora:
  
services:
  collabora:
    image: collabora/code
    container_name: collabora
    environment:
      - domain=example.com
    ports:
      - "9980:9980"
    volumes:
      - ./appdata/collabora:/config 
    networks:
      - collabora
```

In this file, the domain parameter is example.com but my actual domain is something I'd like to keep private.

What is the 'conventional' approach to using a repo with sensitive data? My back up plan is to use a shell script to set some environment variables and then figure out how to refer to those in docker-compose. Then my .sh script would not be added to the repo.

After hearing the phrase 'github secrets' at work I did some searching for expressions along those lines and found results referring to 'secrets' but these seem to be within the use case of Github actions.

What's the 'right' way to store my example docker-compose above with a disguised or hidden domain field?

Comment: A  couple of options include passing environment variables in a `.env` file that isn't committed or with the `-e` switch from the command line with docker.

Comment: If you use docker swarm there is also support for secrets which will mount your stored secrets as text in files within the container.